# If $ f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Integrable and $A⊆I$ has content then $f$ is Integrable on A

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ be a closed cell and let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Integrable on $I$. If $A \subseteq I$ has content then the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is integrable on $A$.

I know i need to use the Riemann Criterion for Integrability but I hope to have some hint on how to apply it.

Comment: what do you mean by ' has content'?? Do you mean that it does not have content zero?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has content, its boundary $\partial A$ has content zero (this property holds for sets with content, but fails for Lebesgue measurable sets). Hence, if you consider the set $\chi_A f$, the only new points of discontinuity you have created are the ones on $\partial A$. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, its set $F$ of discontinuity points has Lebesgue measure zero. If you had to $F$ the set $\partial A$ you still have a set of Lebesgue measure zero and so $\chi_A f$ is Riemann integrable.